# Prevent formatting in some places in string python

Tags: python, string, formatting

I want to format a string with a few variables. But I have more text in the string that is surround by curly braces, but I don't want to format that. I have tried writing it with backslashes: `\{content\}` but that didn't work either. How do I achieve this?

Example:

```py
string = \
"""
{user}'s email is {email}.
{This} is in {curly} {braces}.
"""

print(string.format(user="Foo", email="Bar"))
```

I don't want to format "This", "curly", and "braces".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want keep `curly braces` you should try with

```
string = \
"""
{user}'s email is {email}.
{{This}} is in {{curly}} {{braces}}.
"""

print(string.format(user="Foo", email="Bar"))
# Foo's email is Bar.
# {This} is in {curly} {braces}.
```

Answer (score 2):

The brace can be escaped by doubling: `{{` and `}}`.

```
string = \
"""
{user}'s email is {email}.
{{This}} is in {{curly}} {{braces}}.
"""

print(string.format(user="Foo", email="Bar"))
```

Here is the relevant doc: [python format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)